# How to open an API url with javascript function, how to transfer a variable from html to ts file

Tags: javascript, html, api, ionic4, inappbrowser

I am using newsapi for my current project. It is easy to open 'data.url' using the html page itself.

```
[href]='data.url'
```

My challenge is trying to open the url using a function because just pasting 'data'url' as the link to be opened by InAppBrowser plugin leads me to 'localhost:8010/data.url'. this is my former code.

```
    <ion-item *ngFor="let data of fetchedData?.articles; index as i" [href]="data.url" target="_blank" >
```

this is my new code. HTML

```
    <ion-item *ngFor="let data of fetchedData?.articles; index as i" (click)="openPage()" >
```

.ts

```
 openPage() {
  this.fetchedData = data
  this.iab.create('data.url', '_blank');

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have now realized that the answer is this

```
    <ion-item *ngFor="let data of fetchedData?.articles; index as i" (click)="openPage(data.url)" >
```

instead of this

```
    <ion-item *ngFor="let data of fetchedData?.articles; index as i" (click)="openPage()">
```

and then in the .ts file, I was meant to write...

```
 openPage(url) { // here data.url is assigned to 'url'
  this.iab.create(url, '_blank'); //'url' is called here to be opened in-app

  }
javascript
```

I hope this helps somebody with the same problem